# get_template_directory and/or get_stylesheet_directory enqueuing wrong path

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a local WordPress install and I am trying to enqueue some stylesheets like I've done many times before but I've never run into this bug before.

Here is my code in the functions.php file.

```
function foundation_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'foundation', get_template_directory() . '/css/foundation.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foundation_styles' );
```

When viewing page source this is the file path that was enqueued:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='foundation-css'  href='http://localhost/FoundationwebsiteC:xampphtdocsFoundationwebsite/wp-content/themes/foundation/css/foundation.css?ver=4.0' >
```

Instead it should be:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='foundation-css'  href='http://localhost/Foundationwebsite/wp-content/themes/foundation/css/foundation.css?ver=4.0' >
```

Notice the `C:xampphtdocsFoundationwebsite/` hidden in the middle of the file path.

The exact same thing happened when I used `get_stylesheet_directory()` instead of `get_template_directory()`

The filepath for my local install is:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Foundationwebsite\wp-content\themes\foundation\css
```

Anyone know what is causing my filepath to be so funky?

Answer (score 3):

You're using functions that will return a path whereas what you need is a URL.

Replace `get_template_directory()` or `get_stylesheet_directory()` with `get_template_directory_uri()` or `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

Example:

```
function foundation_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'foundation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/foundation.css' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
function foundation_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'foundation', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/css/foundation.css' );
}
```

for more information refer this link
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style